# How do you rotate all the objects around the camera?

Tags: java, 3d, mathematics, algorithm, javafx

If I'm correct, the way that you can "look around" in an environment is that you rotate all the objects around the camera. This is the code that I've created using JavaFX 3D. So what's the algorithm?

```
package com.rtek.main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.shape.Box;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Walk extends Application {
    private Group root = new Group();
    private PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
    private CameraGroup cameraX = new CameraGroup();
    private CameraGroup cameraY = new CameraGroup();
    private CameraGroup cameraZ = new CameraGroup();
    private static final double CAMERA_INITIAL_DISTANCE = -450;
    private static final double CAMERA_NEAR_CLIP = 0.1;
    private static final double CAMERA_FAR_CLIP = 10000.0;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600, true);

        buildScene();
        buildMouse();

        loadMouse(scene);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Walk Around");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void loadMouse(Scene scene) {
        scene.setOnMouseMoved(event -> {
           ??? 
        });
    }

    private void buildMouse() {
        root.getChildren().add(cameraX);
        cameraX.getChildren().add(cameraY);
        cameraY.getChildren().add(cameraZ);
        cameraZ.getChildren().add(camera);

        camera.setNearClip(CAMERA_NEAR_CLIP);
        camera.setFarClip(CAMERA_FAR_CLIP);
        camera.setTranslateZ(CAMERA_INITIAL_DISTANCE);
    }

    private void buildScene() {
        PhongMaterial material = new PhongMaterial();
        material.setDiffuseColor(Color.RED);
        material.setDiffuseColor(Color.GREEN);

        Box cube = new Box(100, 100, 100);
        cube.setMaterial(material);

        root.getChildren().add(cube);
    }

    private class CameraGroup extends Group {
        private Rotate x = new Rotate();
        private Rotate y = new Rotate();
        private Rotate z = new Rotate();

        public CameraGroup(){
            x.setAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
            y.setAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
            z.setAxis(Rotate.Z_AXIS);

            getTransforms().addAll(x, y, z);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way to "look around" in a 3d environment is to "rotate your camera".

Your assumption to "move the objects around the camera" probably comes from the fact that when you *render* your scene, the MVP (model-view-projection) matrix stack transforms all your objects.

Human beings like to think in what they figure out. And their world is in 3d, and when they move a camera, they like to think that they actually move the camera.

So 3d engines mimics real world objects, with their "real" positions and orientations. So when you use/program a 3d engine, you have to make the camera as if it were an actual real world camera.

Then under the hood, if your graphics pipeline requires it (like OpenGL) you do the transformation at that level.